# Renci SSH.NET doesn't return complete result

Tags: .net, vb.net, ssh, ssh.net

I need a program to send switches some commands and analyse their returned echo. So I wrote some code to send and get echo string. However, I found out some strange phenomenon.

Sometimes, I find the echo returned came from the previous command instead of the current one. To get the correct echo, I have to send the command twice.

Sometimes, I find the echo returned is merely an empty string, which made me add a goto to my code to resend the command if the return value is "".

Sometimes, I find the echo returned is randomly truncated at the end. The next echo starts with the lost part of the previous one. This troubled me badly and I have no idea how to fix this properly.

Function for connecting:

```
Public Sub connect(ip As String, un As String, pw As String, port As Integer)
    ci = New ConnectionInfo(ip,port,un,New AuthenticationMethod(){New PasswordAuthenticationMethod(un,pw)})
    sc = New SshClient(ci)
    sc.Connect()
    ss = sc.CreateShellStream("termi",4000,4000,4000,4000)
End Sub
```

Function for sending command and getting echo:

```
Public Function interact(input As String) As String
    tag1:
    If Not sc.IsConnected Then
        MessageBox.Show("disconnection occured")
        sc.Connect()
    End If
    ss.WriteLine(input)
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)'in case the incomplete echo is because of switch's processing is not finished
    Dim rtn As String = ss.Read()
    If rtn = "" Then
        GoTo tag1
    End If
    Return rtn
End Function
```

At last, ci is ConnectionInfo, sc is SshClient, ss is ShellStream
I cannot be more grateful if anyone can solve me this problem

Comment: Please remove C# tag.  This is VB code.

Comment: @Neil Thanks. I've removed the tag. I did so because I thought people who uses C# are much more than vb and these two languages are so similar. So add a c# might get more answers hahahaha

Comment: Any kind of TCP connection is a stream, not a packet. You cannot just 'wait' for data to arrive and think you have received it all.  You need a protocol that includes how many bytes of data is in a packet, so you know when it has all arrived.  `ss.Read()` will return "" when there is no data in the input buffer, but that doesn't mean there is no more data on its way.

Comment: As @Neil wrote (though it's even more complicated as it's a shell output stream on top of SSH channel stream on top of TCP stream) + If you need more help, we need [mcve]. You have posted two disconnected code snippets only.

Comment: @Neil Hi! So is there a way to aquire on-the-way data? Is enough long Sleep, like Sleep(2000), can solve this problem? Or is there a way to get a pattern of end-of-stream? Thank you